# how send data as cookie without path restriction

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies

How can I add data to a cookie without restricting the cookie to the current web app?

I'm using Java environment (JSPs & Servlets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie `domain and path` attributes define the scope of the cookie. They will tell the browser that the cookie should be sent back to the server for that domain and path.

It not specified , these values default to the domain and the application accessed.

If you want the cookie to be sent for all the applications for that domain:

Set the cookie path just as `/` instead of `/path`